# How to remove specific column of gridview in ASP.net using vb

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am searching the answer for this in google but what i found is not working.
I populate my gridview using a sql query:

```
adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl.scanner", con)
adapter.Fill(ds)
tblasset.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
tblasset.DataBind()
```

This is my code for removing specific column in my gridview:

```
tblasset.Columns(1).Visible = False
```

this code is not working.

the number of columns i have in there is 10. the error is :

```
Index out of range
```

Why is this happening? is my code wrong? pls help me i'm a newbie in asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work, if the GridView columns are known at design time, you can set the `cell(1).Visible` property to `false` in your [`GridView.RowCreated Event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

```
Sub tblasset_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
   e.Row.Cells(1).Visible = false;
End Sub
```

Remember to attach the event in the aspx page.

```
<asp:GridView ID="tblasset" 
              OnRowCreated="tblasset_RowCreated"  
   ..........
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when i first try its not working, then I change the code a little bit, here it is: 

 "Private Sub tblasset_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles tblasset.RowCreated
      
        e.Row.Cells(0).Visible = False
    End Sub"

and its working now, thank you again very much! :)

Comment: @RoronoaZoro, yes my first version of the answer wasn't taking your gridview name in account. glad it worked :)